# fb:login-button custom?

Tags: facebook

Is is possible to add parameters to `fb:login-button` in Facebook Connect?

I would change the text in a more clear way for my target/demographic, who are not so geeky.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

[Yes it is](http://fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:login-button)

```html
<h1>Defaults</h1>
<fb:login-button onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
</fb:login-button>

<h1>autologoutlink</h1>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Small with Custom Text</h1>
<fb:login-button size="small"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Connect
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Medium with Custom Text</h1>
<fb:login-button size="medium"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Connect with Facebook
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Large with Custom Text</h1>
<fb:login-button size="large"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Login with Facebook
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Extra Large with Custom Text</h1>
<fb:login-button size="xlarge"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Find Friends
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Favicon Only</h1>
<fb:login-button size="icon"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
</fb:login-button>
```

Answer (score 4):

**use**

```
{exp:fbc:login_button} content {/exp:fbc:login_button}
```

or

```
<fb:login-button size="medium"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Connect with Facebook
</fb:login-button>
```

http://www.fbrell.com/xfbml/fb:login-button