# FBLogin button resizing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios, fbconnect

I want to imblement facebook into my app, and I downloaded the FBConnect API, and I want to implement FBConnect into iPad, and I need to make the FBLoginButton bigger, but the image inside it doesn't resize to it's frame, does anybody know a solution for this?

Comment: You might need to dig into the code of the FBLoginButton and change the view properties to auto resize. At this point, it looks like facebook has locked it down to encourage consistency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this applies to iPad FB API too, but you should take a look.

The question is about changing the text of the button, but if you see the code it also changes the size with a `size` parameter:

[fb:login-button custom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792231/fblogin-button-custom)

Comment: I managed to solve it just comment the line _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter; in FBLoginButton.m

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Defaults</h1>
<fb:login-button onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
</fb:login-button>

<h1>autologoutlink</h1>
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Small with Custom Text</h1>
<fb:login-button size="small"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Connect
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Medium with Custom Text</h1>
<fb:login-button size="medium"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Connect with Facebook
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Large with Custom Text</h1>
<fb:login-button size="large"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Login with Facebook
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Extra Large with Custom Text</h1>
<fb:login-button size="xlarge"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
  Find Friends
</fb:login-button>

<h1>Favicon Only</h1>
<fb:login-button size="icon"
                 onlogin="Log.info('onlogin callback')">
</fb:login-button>
```

More Information

[fb:login-button custom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792231/fblogin-button-custom)